# What is the impact of disabling the Immediate Alerts Timer Job?

Tags: 2007

We would like to limit the number of emails that is being sent from SharePoint when items are submitted for approval.  In particular we don't see a need for the Task Assigned Email.

Is the Immediate Alerts timer job specifically for sending Task Assigned emails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stop the immediate timer job to stop emails being sent on task assignment, in stead you can go to the task lists > Actions> Settings > Advanced Settings and untick the email notification when ownership assigned.

Hope this helps

Renzo

Comment: Can this be done for the Pages library?

Comment: What do you mean for the pages library ?